# Add html parameters for jquery ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery to make ajax calls to a database which displays the returned records in a div. This works fine but I'm using a hack that breaks w3c validation in order to pass the parameter to the ajax call (i.e. The id to retrieve records from the database for)

My list of hyperlinks is generated in php by getting valid categories from the database and outputting hyperlinks with parameters such as 'blah.php?cat_id=6'. 
The hack is to just also have cat_id = x inside each of the  tags (where x is the category id) which jquery then passes to the backend in the ajax call.

Is there a way to get this data to the ajax call without setting it inside the  tag like I am? I can't use jquery to create the list if hyperlinks because I want it to fallback seamlessly when JS is disabled.
The ids will not come out of the database sequentially so while the jquery data() function seems to be the way to go, I can't figure out how to get the category id to assign to each DOM element (without messy regex parsing on the url parameters from the string)

Thanks
Aaron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use HTML5 `data-*` attributes:

```
<a data-cat-id="6" href="...">
```

You can then read it using jQuery's `data` API:

```
$(this).data('cat-id')
```

Comment: And this is safe to do even if the doctype is not HTML 5.

Comment: And how would this still work if js was turned off ? How would he be able to pass the `cat_id` to the php script.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: He also needs it in the `href`; there is no way around that.  Duplicating the ID is better than parsing the URL and adding a dependency on the URL formats.

Comment: Ahh ok, gotcha, you weren't suggesting taking it off the `href` which i wrongly assumed.

Comment: @dgvid was that a question or a statement? (i.e. My doc type is xhtml strict, will this still cause validation errors?)

Comment: @Alpaus: It's a statement, but he was referring to functionality, not validation.  I don't think this is valid XHTML; I believe the correct solution for XHTML would be to make your own XML namespace.  Just use HTML5; it's simpler.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for clarifying and thanks for a concise and accurate answer.